# For Ruby on Rails, when we run "rails server" (or script/server), what is the sequence of events happening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know `environment.rb`, `environments/development.rb`, `initializers/foobar.rb` will run one by one and in this order (as I put some print statements at the top of those files and see the sequence).

Beside these files, which files get run or get looked at, and in what sequence (update: and what causes it to happen?), when we start a Rails server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help you find out it detail:

- For Current Rails (3.0.x): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html (thanks @Jack Chu)
- For Edge Rails (3.1.x): http://ryanbigg.com/guides/initialization.html
- For older Rails (from circa 2008): http://railsguts.com/initialization.html

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html this link is probably better. The first one is actually for 3.1 or edge rails.

Comment: oh my god,  I looked at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html and thought, wow, that's a good 20 pages of docs, and so I wanted to see how many pages actually, so I printed it as PDF file on a Mac, and looked at it -- 108 pages, my dear friend